# Why can't I answer a question

Tags: support, protected-questions

[This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/why-does-wifi-show-an-error-whenever-i-try-to-reconnect-galaxy-ace) question is protected and requires at least 10 reputation to answer. I have 101 reputation, but I am not able to enter an answer. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to have earned 10 rep *on this site*. The 100 rep association bonus does not count towards that, as explained in [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question).

I will remove the protection lock for now since the question is on the older side and probably not getting as much traffic as it was previously.